# Bootstrap dropdown RTL alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, right-to-left

Recently in the last release of bootstrap (3.2.0), I just realized that we cannot align `dropdowns` with `dir="rtl"` or`dir="ltr"` so we have to do it manually as their [official blog says](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/01/30/bootstrap-3-1-0-released/): (This feature added from version 3.1.0)

> Dropdowns now have their own alignment classes for easier customization

What is that class and how can I make a dropdown list right to left?

Comment: Actually the *last* version is v3.2.0 at the moment.

Comment: @HashemQolami Yeah this happened from version 3.1.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap's new dropdown alignment is quite different than what you are after. It only changes the position of absolutely positioned dropdown menu. I.e. it won't make the dropdown appear in RTL (Right To Left) mode.

Before v3.1.0 [`.pull-right`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.0/less/dropdowns.less#L51) had been used to move the dropdown to the right side of its containing block. However as of v3.1.0 it became *deprecated* in favor of [`.dropdown-menu-right`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.0/less/dropdowns.less#L135)/[`.dropdown-menu-left`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.0/less/dropdowns.less#L145):

> **[Deprecated .pull-right alignment](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment)**
>
> As of v3.1.0, we've deprecated `.pull-right` on dropdown menus. To
> right-align a menu, use `.dropdown-menu-right`. Right-aligned nav
> components in the navbar use a mixin version of this class to
> automatically align the menu. To override it, use
> `.dropdown-menu-left`.

But it doesn't give the RTL effect as mentioned before.

#RTL Mode

> What is that class and how can I make a dropdown list right to left?

In order to achieve that you could give `direction: rtl;` to the `.dropdown` element and also override the default `text-align: left` of `.dropdown-menu` with `text-align: right`<sup>1</sup>.

Besides, you have to move the absolutely positioned dropdown menu to the right via `.dropdown-menu-right` as well. Hence you'll end up with something like this:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/nafole/3/edit)**

```css
.rtl { direction: rtl; }
.rtl .dropdown-menu-right { text-align: right; }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown rtl">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I strongly recommend to use an additional class name in order not to change the Twitter Bootstrap's default styling of `.dropdown`.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Now you have to use `.dropdown-menu-right` and `.dropdown-menu-left`

See discussion [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10370) and [examples at Bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment)

Answer (score 2):

this is example to use rtl , Arabic language  with bootstrap 5 :

1- Set dir="rtl" on the 'html' tag element.

2- Add an appropriate lang attribute , like lang="ar" , on the 'html' tag element.

3- for dropdown menu rtl , just use "dropdown-menu-end  text-end" classes as the following  :

```
    <li className="nav-item dropdown" >                 
                <a   className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                test drown rtl
                </a>
                <ul  className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end  text-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                    <li className="float-end"><a  href="#" className="dropdown-item ">تعديل الملف الشخصي</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="#" className="dropdown-item" >تعديل كلمة المرور </a></li>
                    <li><hr className="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                
                    <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#">تسجيل الخروج</a></li>
                                            
                </ul>
    </li>
```

i hope this helpful  for every one will use bootstrap5 rtl dropdown-menu.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new file `_rtl.scss` and imported it after bootstrap.
This is its the content:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  text-align: start !important;
  float: right !important;
  left: initial !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}
```

That way the dropdown will always open from the right side of the button.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

add this on css style for bootstrap 4

```
    .dropdown-menu {
        left: 0 !important;
        right: auto !important;
    }
```